# Cut string from the first number from the left using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the column letters of a range for a macro. I specifically need the column letters, the numbers you get for columns directly using VBA `Address` functions won't work. Since the ranges are always from one column only, this simplifies the task. The range retrieved could be something like `B3` or `B3:B5`, but always the same column and are inside a table.

So, what I need (in this case) to get would be `B` as a string. I tried to do the following:

```
RangeOfInterest = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[Column1]").Address(0, 0)
RangeColumn = Right(RangeOfInterest, Len(RangeOfInterest) - InStr(RangeOfInterest, [0-9]))
```

However, I run into a series of issues with this. First, there is the `InStr` function. I thought this was the best way, because this function searches for the position of a character starting from the left, which is exactly what I need. However, I would need it to search for many values (any number from 0 to 9). Could I add all the numbers as search arguments or use some kind of trick to search between a range of numbers? What I tried certainly doesn't work.

On the other hand, I assume that if I somehow manage to add all numbers from 0 to 9, the function would start searching for them one by one instead of stopping the first time there is any number in the string? This would result in the issue that if for example there is a range like `B3:B10` it will begin searching for a 0 and return the position of the 0 and finish, hence my code will return the string `B3:B1` instead of just `B`.

Also, I can't just use a fixed solution like `Left(RangeOfInterest, 1)` to get the `B` because the code should work with any range, and once you reach the Z the column letters are double and go like AA, AB and so on.

I thought that another alternative would be to loop, but all my tries resulted in very complex pieces of code for what seems to have a pretty easy solution. Also, if possible, I would like to avoid looping although that doesn't matter if there is no other option. I would really appreciate any suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Tried the column function?

Comment: As per @Solar Mike’s suggestion above, once you have the column number – say you call it `ColNum` - then it’s relatively easy to get the letter.  `ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColNum).Address, "$")(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More often, one wants the number of a columns than its name because if you feed Excel the name it will convert it to the corresponding number for processing. Therefore I hope it isn't that you need the name for the purpose of addressing a cell using VBA. Anyway, here you go:-

```
 Dim RangeOfInterest As String
    
    RangeOfInterest = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Table1[Column1]").EntireColumn.Address(0, 0)
    RangeOfInterest = Split(RangeOfInterest, ":")(0)
    Debug.Print RangeOfInterest
```

Comment: Yes! I do prefer working with column numbers instead of letters. My problem is that I'm patching a macro instead of creating a new one, and the person who coded it kinda hard coded many things, and changing this would break everything. Your solution works perfectly, thank you very much.